# Variable in recordset destination replaced when the dataflow is in For Each loop container?

Tags: ssis, recordset, foreach-loop-container

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets. So In For Each loop container have a script which is reading the sheets and saving them to the variable. In dataflow still inside of the For Each loop container is the process which leads to recordset destination which is saving all the columns to another variable. Then outside of the for each loop container is another dataflow which has to read from the variable all rows check for duplicity (in second and 3 sheet is duplicit product id), remove duplicity and upload data into database. I have been searching everywhere and cannot find how to setup the recordset destination to not replace the variable but append it with the values, because end up only with last sheet of data.

Cannot be doing changes in the foreach loop container in settings because of the looping through the sheets.

Thank you in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

While hopefully someone wiser in SSIS will chime in here, but I don't think your current approach will work.

Generally speaking, you can use Expressions within SSIS to get dynamic behaviour. However, the VariableName of the Recordset Destination does not support that.

You *might* be able to have a Script Task after the Data Flow that copies from `rsCurrent` into rsIteration1, rsIteration2, etc based on the current loop but at that point, you're double copying data for no *real* value.

Since you're doing a duplicate check, perhaps a read of sheet 1 goes into a [Cache Connection Manager](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-excel-in-ssis-lookup.html)

And then the read from subsequent pages will use the CCM as the lookup. For rows that have matches, then you know you have duplicates (or maybe you only import what doesn't match, I don't quite get your logic)

Debugging some of this is going to be quite challenging. If at all possible, I would stage the data to tables. There you could load all the data + the tab name and then you can test your deduplication and refer back to your inputs and outputs.

The tooling for SSIS variables of type Object is pretty limited, which is a pity.